# Why no Description on error 80070002?

Tags: windows, vbscript

From some Visual Basic Script I accidentally tried to launch a program that did not exist:

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
On Error Resume Next
WshShell.Run "incorrect"
WScript.Echo "Error:"  & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
             "Code:"   & vbTab & Hex(Err.Number)
```

That gives:

```
Error:  
Code:   80070002
```

So *no description*.

When I disable error checking (comment out the `On Error Resume Next`), I *do* get a description:

```
---------------------------
Windows Script Host
---------------------------
Script: D:\Folder\MyScript.vbs
Line:   3
Char:   1
Error:  The system cannot find the file specified. 
Code:   80070002
Source:     (null)

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Is this difference in behavior a bug? Or am I missing something? I cannot find this documented anywhere.

Comment: Interesting I've just tested this with the same result, not sure why it happens but will investigate.

Comment: Well found this old [Doctor Scripto's Script Shop: To Err Is VBScript – Part 1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee692852.aspx) article. About halfway through the article the difference in behaviour is touched on but never fully explained.

Comment: Quote - *"If you're one of those people who noticed that in Listing 2 the Source and Description properties were empty, but here for the same error they return values, you're probably scratching your head right about now. So are we. Just remember, scripting without mysteries would be insipid and boring. But since you ask, Doctor Scripto is going out on a limb and speculating that it may have something to do with how Listing 2 instantiated the particular Win32_Printer object directly without first creating a WMI service object:"*. Not sure how much this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I've done some testing myself and it appears to only happen with `WshShell.Run()`.
For example try the following code which will work the same way but note the output.

```vb
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
On Error Resume Next
'This line will fail because there is no Type of 88.
WshShell.LogEvent 88, "incorrect"
WScript.Echo "Error:"  & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
             "Code:"   & vbTab & Hex(Err.Number)
```

Output *(with `On Error Resume Next`)*:

```
Error:  Invalid procedure call or argument
Code:   5
```

Output *(without `On Error Resume Next`)*:

```
Error:  Invalid procedure call or argument
Code:   5
```

My guess is that `WshShell.Run()` is only reading from `StdOut` and not `StdErr` when `On Error Resume Next` is used, this is unique to `WshShell.Run()` because it is attempting to create a new process.

You could take this further by perhaps testing using `WshShell.Exec()` which gives access to both output streams.

```vb
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
On Error Resume Next
Set WshExec = WshShell.Exec("incorrect")
WScript.Echo "Error:"  & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
             "Code:"   & vbTab & Hex(Err.Number)
```

Weirdly checked both `WshExec.StdOut` and `WshExec.StdErr` and neither contain the error output but the method behaves as expected when `On Error Resume Next` is used.

So not by any means conclusive.

But as the [accompanying article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee692852.aspx) states;

> *Just remember, scripting without mysteries would be insipid and boring*

---

#### Useful Links

- [Doctor Scripto's Script Shop: To Err Is VBScript – Part 1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee692852.aspx)

Comment: Why would `StdOut` and `StdErr` be relevant here? No process is started, so where would the output come from?

Comment: @MicheldeRuiter It's a guess *(which I have stated)* based on what `Run()` is attempting to do, at some point when `Run()` passes control to the subsystem to execute the process *(fictitious or not)* the full error output is lost, this only happens for the `Run()` method so is *fairly safe to assume* it is to do with that subsystem process.

Comment: @MicheldeRuiter Did you try the `WshShell.Exec()` equivalent example?